# Karma\jasmine timeout without any errors

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner, google-chrome-headless

I have an issue with running unit tests in my app. For some reasons when i run tests, running is stops on some test with any mistake, it can be systemic, it is stop all the time in one test, but when i find this test and comment it, running stops on another test. But there is strange thing that it happens not all the time. Some times tests running well and the when i try to run files with "problems" with fdescribe or with fit everything is ok too. I'll be very grateful is somebody help me with this issue, because i spent a lot of hour to solve that problem tried different config to karma.conf.js and nothing helps me... it is not a first project that work on, i have tried to use same config, it didn't help me.

package.json

```
  "name": "project",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --disable-host-check --host=0.0.0.0 --poll=100",
    "build-production": "ng build --prod --progress=false",
    "build-staging": "ng build --configuration=staging --progress=false",
    "build-test": "ng build --configuration=test --progress=false",
    "test": "ng test --watch=false --progress=false",
    "code-coverage": "ng test --code-coverage",
    "test:ci": "ng test --watch=false --progress=false",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "format:fix": "pretty-quick --staged",
    "format:check": "prettier --config ./.prettierrc --list-different \"src/{app,environments,assets}/**/*{.ts,.js,.json,.css,.scss}\""
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "8.2.7",
    "@angular/compiler": "8.2.7",
    "@angular/core": "8.2.7",
    "@angular/forms": "8.2.7",
    "@angular/http": "7.2.15",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "8.2.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "8.2.7",
    "@angular/router": "8.2.7",
    "@ngxs/storage-plugin": "3.5.1",
    "@ngxs/store": "3.5.1",
    "@sentry/browser": "5.6.3",
    "@sq-ui/ng-sq-ui": "1.1.5",
    "angular-google-charts": "0.1.6",
    "angular-token": "7.0.1",
    "chart.js": "2.8.0",
    "core-js": "2.5.7",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "1.4.2",
    "lodash": "4.17.15",
    "moment": "2.24.0",
    "moment-timezone": "0.5.26",
    "ng-bullet": "1.0.3",
    "ngx-twitter-timeline": "0.1.5",
    "node-sass": "4.12.0",
    "prettier": "1.18.2",
    "rxjs": "6.5.3",
    "rxjs-compat": "6.5.3",
    "rxjs-tslint": "0.1.7",
    "semantic-ui-css": "2.4.1",
    "sentry": "0.1.2",
    "zone.js": "0.10.2"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=8.5.0",
    "yarn": ">=1.3.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "0.803.5",
    "@angular/cli": "8.3.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "8.2.7",
    "@ngxs/devtools-plugin": "3.5.1",
    "@types/crypto-js": "3.1.43",
    "@types/jasmine": "3.5.0",
    "@types/node": "12.7.5",
    "codelyzer": "5.2.0",
    "husky": "3.0.5",
    "intl": "1.2.5",
    "jasmine-core": "3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "4.2.1",
    "karma": "4.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "3.1.0",
    "karma-cli": "2.0.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "2.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "2.0.1",
    "karma-spec-reporter": "0.0.32",
    "ng2-semantic-ui": "0.10.0-alpha.6",
    "pretty-quick": "1.11.1",
    "protractor": "5.4.2",
    "ts-node": "8.4.1",
    "tslint": "5.20.0",
    "typescript": "3.5.3"
  }
}
```

karma.conf.js

```
module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular-devkit/build-angular'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
      require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
      require('@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma')
    ],
    client: {
      clearContext: false, // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
      jasmine: {
        random: false
      }
    },
    coverageIstanbulReporter: {
      dir: require('path').join(__dirname, '../coverage'),
      reports: ['html', 'lcovonly'],
      fixWebpackSourcePaths: true
    },
    captureTimeout: 60000,
    browserDisconnectTolerance: 1,
    browserDisconnectTimeout : 60000,
    browserNoActivityTimeout : 60000,
    reporters: ['progress', 'kjhtml'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['ChromeHeadlessNoSandbox'],
    customLaunchers: {
      ChromeHeadlessNoSandbox: {
        base: 'ChromeHeadless',
        flags: [
                '--no-sandbox',
                '--disable-gpu',
                '--enable-logging',
                '--no-default-browser-check',
                '--no-first-run',
                '--disable-default-apps',
                '--disable-popup-blocking',
                '--disable-translate',
                '--disable-background-timer-throttling',
                '--disable-renderer-backgrounding',
                '--disable-device-discovery-notifications',
                '--remote-debugging-port=9222',
                '--disable-web-security'
        ]
      }
    },
    singleRun: false
  });
};
```

I have output like this:

```
HeadlessChrome 78.0.3904 (Mac OS X 10.14.6): Executed 39 of 219 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0.286 secs)
06 12 2019 09:21:52.239:WARN [HeadlessChrome 78.0.3904 (Mac OS X 10.14.6)]: Disconnected (0 times), becauHeadlessChrome 78.0.3904 (Mac OS X 10.14.6) ERROR
  Disconnected, because no message in 60000 ms.
HeadlessChrome 78.0.3904 (Mac OS X 10.14.6): Executed 39 of 219 DISCONNECTED (1 min 1.163 secs / 0.286 secs)
HeadlessChrome 78.0.3904 (Mac OS X 10.14.6) ERROR
HeadlessChrome 78.0.3904 (Mac OS X 10.14.6): Executed 39 of 219 DISCONNECTED (1 min 1.163 secs / 0.286 secs)
```